# Error in computing the confusino matrix of a logistic model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I created in r-studio a null logistic model.

```
nullModel <- glm(train$bigFire ~ 1, data = train, family = binomial)
```

Then it is asked to the model to make predictions on the test-set.

```
nullModel.pred <- predict(nullModel, test, type = "response")
```

At this point i want to compute the confusion matrix in order to evaluate the performances of the model.

```
CM <- table(test$bigFire, nullModel.pred>0.5)
```

The resulting output is the following:

```
    TRUE
  0   58
  1   46
```

Even if i change the cutoff value (now set to 0.5) the result is always the same. I don't understand why since the model should perform in a different way having different cutoff values.

The dataset is the following:

```
  month day FFMC  DMC    DC  ISI temp RH wind rain zone bigFire
1   mar fri 86.2 26.2  94.3  5.1  8.2 51  6.7  0.0   75       0
2   oct tue 90.6 35.4 669.1  6.7 18.0 33  0.9  0.0   74       0
3   oct sat 90.6 43.7 686.9  6.7 14.6 33  1.3  0.0   74       0
4   mar fri 91.7 33.3  77.5  9.0  8.3 97  4.0  0.2   86       0
5   mar sun 89.3 51.3 102.2  9.6 11.4 99  1.8  0.0   86       0
6   aug sun 92.3 85.3 488.0 14.7 22.2 29  5.4  0.0   86       0
```

It counts 517 rows.
The test and train are generated from the previous datafram with a split of 80% for train and 20% for test (104 rows).
The length of the prediction vector is:

```
> length(nullModel.pred)
[1] 104
```

and contains always the same value -> 0.542.
This is reasonable since it is only able to estimate the expected value for the response to be 1.

Comment: Does `nullModel.pred` look right when you examine it before trying to make a confusion matrix? How about `test$bigFire`? There's nothing obviously wrong in the code you've shared, so you need to give us some more info / make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Difficult without sample data, but anyway. Try: `table(test$bigFire, round(nullModel.pred))`

Comment: you are fitting an intercept only model so the predictions will be a constant; either all greater or all lower than 0.5. As you change the cutoff, you should see either all TRUE or all FALSE

Comment: And this works, but the confusion matrix remains the same.

Comment: The numbers in the confusion  matrix should stay the same but the column label should either be TRUE or FALSE. The only way it would not change is if the predictions were all exactly zero. If you are not seeing this can you share `nullModel.pred[1:10]` please.

Comment: Yes. if i change the cutoff value, after a trheshold, it shows a column of true or a column of false.

Comment: so that's working as expected. (e.g. if we only have one column, as the cut-off is changed, the numbers will stay the same and only the column label will change. The number of zeros/ones in the test dataset is unchanged and so the rows sums will stay the same )